# What does the appeals process look like if you are denied entry to the United States?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, denial-of-entry

I'm a British Citizen holding an L1 Visa, currently employed in the US.

I may need to travel internationally soon. I am concerned about re-entry to the US at the end of this travel (I may be away for up to 6 months).

I believe the rules currently state that I am permitted to enter (provided I have not been in certain countries in the preceding 14 days). However I am also aware that L1 (and other Visa types) are currently not being issued and I could run into difficulty if the officer on the day is in a bad mood.

Should the officer decide to deny entry, what would be the options presented to me for appeal and how quickly would the process take place?

EDIT - to clarify - There's no reason for me to believe that I'm any more or less likely to be denied entry than an average Brit. Prior to COVID and the presidential proclamations, I was a regular international traveler with Global Entry. I may well be worried about nothing, but forewarned is forearmed and that is the purpose of this question.

Comment: Rule #1 in such cases is: do not travel. If you suspect a border entry rejection is likely, it's best to stay in the US.

Comment: @JonathanReez I made an edit to clarify the reason for asking my question. I honestly don't think it's likely, but I think the probability of being rejected has increased due to COVID.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.justlanded.com/english/United-States/Articles/Moving/Refusal-of-entry

Comment: Understood. If it helps, I was traveling on L-1 from Europe in August (with a stay in Turkey for 2 weeks to satisfy the Schengen ban) and the entry was as smooth as ever.

Comment: Visas of any kind (including the L1) do _NOT_ give you the right to be admitted, and there is little you can do if denied entry. Basically, you can apply for a visa again and hope to get a review of the denial, but chances are you get automatically denied again. There is no certaincy, and no legal way to force the US to admit you.

Comment: I think you cannot appeal, but whey you are back, you may ask consular offices about the case, and how to solve the issue. Everybody (but US citizen, and I think green card holders) could be denied (just usually it happens for a reason). Just.. be nice

Comment: My advice is aside from the fact that you cannot appeal, a denial of entry counts against you in a subsequent visa application regardless of what they tell you. One must endeavor to avoid being denied entry as much as possible and preferable defer any travel between now and November or preferably January next year.

Comment: @Aganju I believe that's incorrect.  A traveler who isn't using the VWP can insist on being brought before an immigration judge.  Of course, that might mean a few days in immigration detention.